# Скопировать колонки с одного CSV файла в другой

Tags: phpexcel, php, excel

Мне нужна помощь. Я новый в PHP, у меня есть CSV файл, и в нем 3 столбца

```
product_code         name         price
    e122           card game       20
    e133           dise            25
    e124           ball            47
```

Задача моя, скопировать два столбца product_code и price и вложить его в новый файл CSV при этом цены должны умножиться на 2 в новом файле CSV.

```
product_code         price
    e122              40
    e133              50
    e124              94
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @MichaelVaughn, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (($hi = fopen('php://stdin', "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $ho = fopen('php://stdout', "w");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($hi, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        fwrite($ho, $data[0] . ";" . $data[2] * 2 . "\n");
    }
    fclose($hi);
    fclose($ho);
}
```

Код на [`Ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/XR7X7Y)